# Firestore Rules - get the size of request parameters

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In firestore, `request.resource.data.size()` is equivalent to the size of the document **in its final form**. My question is, how can I get the parameters that are being sent from the client?

Meaning, if I the client tries to update the property `name`, then I want to check if the client has updated `name` and the size of the parameters he sent is just one parameter. I would've used `hasExact()` if it existed, but the problem is that I'm not sure if there's an object the specifies the requested parameters.

With the current `request.resource.data.size()`, I'm not sure how can do the following operations:

1. Deny writing `updatedAt` property (which is being updated as the server timestamp on each update) without an additional property.
2. Deny updating a property that is already equivalent to the requested value.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell from your question exactly what you want to do.  It doesn't sound like the size of the update is the only thing you need to be looking at.  Without a more concrete example, I am just going to guess what you need

But you should know that `request.resource.data` is a [Map](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map) type object.  Click through to the linked API documentation to find out what you can do with a Map.  That map will contain all the fields of a document that's being updated by the client.  If you want the value of one of those fields, you can say `request.resource.data.f` where `f` is the name of the field.  This should help you express your logic.

If you want the value of an existing field of a document, before it's written, use the map `resource.data`, which works the same way.